# direct summands of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative DVR, and let $M$ be the free $R$-module of finite rank $k\ge 2$.
Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$ isomorphic to $R$.

Is it true that $N$ is a direct summand of $M$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In most examples, R has principal ideals I whose corresponding quotients are torsion modules. it follows that I is not a summand of R, and that $I\oplus 0$ is not a summand of $R^2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why $I\oplus 0$ cannot be a summand of $R^2$? $R$ cannot have torsion?

Comment: @Rod Right, $R$ can't have torsion because as a ring it is a domain.

Comment: @Dylan Yes, I missed that. Thank you all.